# Drawing line in finger paint remove the previously drawn image

Tags: android, canvas, paint

am working with painting. when drawing line it draw perfectly. when i draw a new line previously drawn line are removed from the view i don't know why it happens. Anybody know please help me.

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {// custom view
                private Canvas mCanvas;
                private Path mPath;
        private ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();
    private ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();


                public DrawView(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                    setFocusable(true);
                    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

                    mCanvas = new Canvas();

                    mPath = new Path();



                }

                @Override
                protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
                    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);     //do as user want

            }

                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { //onDraw method


                        //DRAWING LINE................................

                        linearray[0]=stupx;
                        linearray[1]=stupy;
                        linearray[2]=upx;
                        linearray[3]=upy;

                         canvas.drawLines(linearray, mPaint);


                         Log.d("METHOD", "ONDRAW LINE FIRED "+stupx+" "+stupy+""+upx+" "+upy);


                }



                private float mX, mY;
                private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

                private void touch_start(float x, float y) {


                    undonePaths.clear();
                    mPath.reset();
                    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;


                }

                private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
                    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                        mX = x;
                        mY = y;
                    }
                }

                private void touchline() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("METHOD", "TOUCHLINE FIRED ");


                    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                    // commit the path to our offscreen
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                // kill this so we don't double draw



                        newShapePaint = new Paint(mPaint); // Clones the mPaint object
                        paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(mPath, newShapePaint));

                        Log.d("TOUCH UP", "METHOD FIRED WITHOUT COLOR CHANGE"+_color);


                    mPath = new Path();
                }

            }
```

// onTouch event

```
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                     x = event.getX();
                     y = event.getY();

                     upx=0f;
                     upy=0f;

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        stupx=event.getX();
                        stupy=event.getY();
                        touch_start(x, y);
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        touch_move(x, y);
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("method", "touch up fired");
                         upx=event.getX();
                         upy=event.getY();


                        touchline();    //call after remove finger


                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call invalidate without any parameter, it invalidates complete screen (Redraws complete screen rectangle) thereby removing your previous line. Try calling invalidate with proper parameter.

Please find below code for fingerPaint. I took this from apidemos :) (apidemos-graphics-fingerpaint):

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class FingerPaint extends GraphicsActivity
        implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
        menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

        /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
        Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(
                              Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                              new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                              null, intent, 0, null);
        *****/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case COLOR_MENU_ID:
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                return true;
            case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sushil. Thats only am struggling there, could you provide any coding to change

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a fingerpaint code. Hope this will help you. I took this code from apidemos and it works :)

Comment: In the code you can see how the previous line is getting committed to offscreen canvas. you just need to do the same thing.

Comment: Just have a look at touch_up() function which is getting called from ACTION_UP. You just need to do this step for you.

Comment: yes i see it. the same way i commited in touchline() method but it doesnt work please see the coding above @ touchline() method

Comment: In your onDraw() your are just drawing the line. You need to draw the bitmap on the canvas which has previous lines saved. Invalidate calls onDraw. So, just draw the canvas in onDraw and it should work

Comment: please could you illustrate with coding

Comment: You just need to do the same thing as it is done in the code I posted. Have a look at it. Declare a bitmap and set it to your canvas. and then do all the drawing using that bitmap.

Comment: How can I implement your code for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521661/change-color-without-affecting-anything-previously-drawn